# jquery event focus alternatives

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I have a table inside a modal that was echoed via PHP. I add a class that whenever the value does not match, the said class will be hidden. The problem is that when the focus is lost in the modal, the class returns to be hidden. Here is excerpt from my php code:

```
echo "<tr class='options1'>
                 <td><label class='control-label'>Section:</label></td>
                  <td><select class='form-control' name='cmbsection' id='cmbsection'>
                  <option value='".$val['Section']."'>".$val['Section']."</option>";
                  $section_code = array();
                  $section_code[] = $val['Section'];
                  foreach($data['sectionlist'] as $value)
                  {
                    if(!in_array($value['sectionName'],$section_code))
                    {
                        echo "<option value='".$value['sectionName']."'>".$value['sectionName']."</option>";
                    }
                  }
                  echo "</select>
                   </td>
                   <td><label class='control-label'>Line:</label></td>
                    <td><select class='form-control' name='cmbline' id='cmbline'>";
                    $line_code = array();
                    $line_code[] = $val['Line'];
                    echo "<option value='".$val['Line']."'>".$val['Line']."</option>";
                    foreach($data['linelist'] as $value)
                    {
                        if(!in_array($value['lineName'],$line_code))
                        {
                            echo "<option value='".$value['lineName']."'>".$value['lineName']."</option>";
                        }
                    }
                    echo "</select>
                     </td>
                     </tr>
```

and here is the jquery code:

```
$(document).on('focus','#modalEditEmployees',function(){
$('tr.options1').hide();
$('#cmbdept3').on('change',function(){
    if($('#cmbdept3 option:selected').text() == "SEWING"){
        $('tr.options1').show();
    }
    else
    {
        $('tr.options1').hide();
    }
});
});
```

Please note that modalEditEmployees is the name of the modal.

Comment: modalEditEmployees is the name of the bootstrap modal that the echoed table resides....

Comment: I tried the load event but it was already deprecated in version 1.8 and up so it's not working...

Comment: Please help I really need this to make it work...